# Disconnect sets are clopen

Tags: real-analysis

> Show that $\partial A=\emptyset$ iff $A$ is clopen (open and closed) iff $A$, $A^c$ disconnect $X$.

Finished:

$\partial A=\emptyset$ iff $A$ is clopen (open and closed)

If $A$ is clopen (open and closed), $A$, $A^c$ disconnect $X$.

Question:

Given $A$, $A^c$ disconnect $X$,

how to show that $\partial A=\emptyset$ or that A is clopen?

Answer (score 0):

A and AC are two separate sets . Then closure of A is a subset of A and similarly for AC